# Calculate column value when I upload document to SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint and trying to explore Content Types, Lists, libraries;
I created my own Content Type called "Salary Report" (Parent - Document) and assigned to my "Salary Report Library".
"Salary Report" content type have only two columns - Date Created and Document (and also hidden Title).

I would like to handle document creation and use Date Created column to store Salary Report Month value by calculating this in code. Are there any options to handle document creation in code (C#/.NET or JavaScript) or how can I handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Microsoft Flow to achieve this.

Step1:

[image]

Step2:get current month   utcNow('MM')

You could know more about this here: https://www.o365dude.com/2017/05/01/working-with-dates-times-in-microsoft-flow/
[image]

Step3:get current file ID
[image]

Step4:call a rest api update column value you want.
[image]

‘date’ is the ordinary column, ’DateCreatedByme’ is the column in content type.